# vb.net crash on deployed application

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net video application that I've deployed to a windows 7 machine using click once. It is crashing on startup with an unhandled exception and I can't figure out what its trying to do.  It does work on other deployed computers.

Following is the trace and I'm hoping someone can help me determine what to look for. All I can see is there a class not registered exception in InteropServices (Interop.MSCommLib.DLL) but not sure what to do to fix it.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
(JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

    ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred creating the
    form. See Exception.InnerException for details.     The error is:
    Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
    (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
    ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:   Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
    (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))  at
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid&
    clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)    at
    System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid
    clsid)    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid
    clsid)    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()    at
    System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()    at
    System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)    at
    System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()    at
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)  
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean
    fIgnoreVisible)  at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()    at
    Player.Apex232.InitializeComponent()    at Player.Apex232..ctor()   
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Player.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance)    at
    Player.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Apex232()    at
    Player.main.tmrInitialize_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)    at
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)   
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
    msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


    ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Player
        Assembly Version: 1.0.4765.16371
        Win32 Version: 1.0.4765.16371
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/Player.exe
    ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualBasic
        Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Core
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Runtime.Remoting
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility
        Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Data
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.237 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
    ---------------------------------------- MySql.Data
        Assembly Version: 6.4.4.0
        Win32 Version: 6.4.4.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/MySql.Data.DLL
    ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
    ---------------------------------------- AxInterop.WMPLib
        Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/AxInterop.WMPLib.DLL
    ---------------------------------------- Interop.WMPLib
        Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/Interop.WMPLib.DLL
    ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Deployment
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs
        Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 10.0.20911.1
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
        Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
    ---------------------------------------- AxInterop.MSCommLib
        Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
        Win32 Version: 1.1.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/AxInterop.MSCommLib.DLL
    ---------------------------------------- Interop.MSCommLib
        Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
        Win32 Version: 1.1.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/1-Admin/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/KNRBJ7QO.TBP/7LLH8JQX.G77/play..tion_0000000000000000_0002.0000_e02e247c5bbc65ce/Interop.MSCommLib.DLL
    ----------------------------------------

    ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
    (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
    system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
    with debugging enabled.

    For example:

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an ActiveX control in your application, judging from the name some video player control or serial port COM object, that is not registered on the machine you deployed your ClickOnce application to. All your ClickOnce application contains is a managed wrapper around the ActiveX control, not the ActiveX control itself.

Installing ActiveX controls with ClickOnce isn't terribly straight forward. You may be able to [bootstrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229432%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the install of your ActiveX control with ClickOnce, or alternatively not use ClickOnce at all and use an MSI that installs the ActiveX control.

Comment: hmm - I'm using Windows Media Player is it considered active X

Comment: @user1916475 Are you using any other ActiveX or COM libraries? `MSCommLib` seems like a COM component for Serial Port reading.

Comment: I do have a module included that does serial communications and I did see an issue in the app where the com port was incorrectly set. I think the problem is that this installation does not have the device installed and I'm trying to implement a way for the app to to still work without the device.  When they get the device, hopefully this goes away.  I am going to close this and I really appreciate your help vcsJones.

Comment: I can disconnect the device on my machine and it works without crashing so I doubt it will work when they get the device.  Any ideas vcsJones? Thanks!

Comment: @user1916475 Don't use `MSCommLib` for serial port communication. Use the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class instead since that is part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: I noticed that on my working machine I have a different driver (ftser2k.sys) whereas the deployed machine is using serenum.sys.

Comment: @user1916475 This is getting a bit out of my zone of expertise. I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: thank you vcsJones I've marked this as answered, you've been a great help and I really appreciate it.